# Self hosting Azure devops build agent on macOS Catalina not working

Tags: macos, .net-core, azure-devops, macos-catalina

I've installed and configured a self-hosted DevOps agent on a mac running Catalina. On the same machine I'm also developing using JetBrains Rider, meaning SDK (.NET Core) is installed.

The agent gets installed and is able to start. I also see the agent in the DevOps portal. But when a pipeline is triggered, the agent is not picking up the job and nothing happens.

Anyone else seen this on mac? For Windows it is running just fine.

Comment: Have you looked at running diagnostics? "If you're having trouble with your self-hosted agent, you can try running diagnostics. After configuring the agent: `./run.sh --diagnostics`" More info: [Self-hosted macOS agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx)

Comment: everything seems just fine

Comment: Is the _correct version_ of .NET Core installed? Is the agent visible and with status online? And in the correct Agent Pool? Did you specify the correct Agent Pool in the build pipeline? Can you get a really simple pipeline to be picked up by the macOS agent? Can your pipeline run on a Microsoft hosted agent (for test purposes)?

Comment: Did you check out the troubleshooting steps in below solution? How did it go?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT I did test it. No luck so far. I'm using default pool and also tested using both default and Default as it is OSX :). My Lenovo machine with windows has no issues picking up the builds. I tried to disable it and then only have the osx agent running, no luck

Comment: Hi @RasmusChristensen Is there any default Demands set up for your pipeline definition? Any message from the build log when you triggered your pipeline against the osx agent?

Answer (score 1):

If the self-hosted agent is correctly installed and you can see its status is online from the Azure devops Portal. see below screenshot.

[image]

Then you need to check if you pipeline is targeting the correct agent pool where the self-hosted macOS agent resides.

If all of the above is correctly setup, and the self-hosted macOS agent is still not picking up the job. This is probably because you have multiple self-hosted agents inside the agent pool, your pipeline will automatically pick one from the agent pool to run your job.

For this case, you can use [Demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#demands) to limit your pipeline only run on the agent whose [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities) satisfy the demands.

You can use predefined capabilities or define custom capabilities from Azure devops Portal

[image]

```
    pool:
      name: MyPool
      demands:
      - Tag -equals macOS 
      - agent.os -equals Darwin
```